# Worth getting USB 3.0 enclosure for old HDD?

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-3, enclosures

I have a WD 500GB MyPassport which is a couple of years old (2009-2010). Will I be able to see a noticeable speed difference if I remove the HDD and use it with a USB 3.0 caddy instead?

Comment: The HDD is unlikely going to benefit from any additional bandwidth USB 3.0 would provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done exactly what you're talking about.  Mine was a portable Seagate USB 2.0 drive (thankfully no proprietary connector/bridge on that one).

Moving it to a USB 3.0 case improved the sequential *read* speed from around 30 MB/s to 60 MB/s.  Sequential *write* speeds improved from around 30 MB/s to 45 MB/s.  I only used the drive for large files so I can't comment on random read/write performance.

Based on my experience, I am confident you would see similar results.  Noticeable improvement?  Probably, for sequential reads/writes (i.e. large files).

Worth doing?  Maybe not given the attractive pricing of new portable USB 3.0 drives.  Besides, the latest USB 3.0 drives are really fast.  My new Toshiba portable drive blazes away at over 100 MB/s sequential read and write.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to put this into a standard USB caddy. From what I remember, drives like this have proprietary connectors attached to the drive itself and it'll only work with that specific case. There *are* however USB 3.0 cases now that are very cheap so it's probably not even worth cracking open your old drive.

Comment: Thanks!
I think they introduced the proprietary bridges to later models so mine should be a standard HDD. Given I can install it to a USB 3.0 enclosure will I see a speed increase?

Comment: Btw, is there a way to check the type of HDD without opening it up?

Comment: If it's SATA, you'll see a sizable increase. USB 2.0 is limited to ~280 Mbits/sec while SATA's maximum bandwidth is 6 Gbps. USB 3.0 allows 4.8 Gbits.

Comment: You may be able to google around with your drive's model to get the internal bits, but my searches pulled the 3.0 version...